# Type issues on using $in mikro orm mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb, typescript, typegraphql, mikro-orm

I am using mikro orm with mongodb for my project. So far it's the best orm for MongoDB in typescript. But I am facing type errors on using $in with Object Id. Here's my code:

```
  @Query(() => [Post])
  async allPosts(@Ctx() { em }: appContext) {
    const posts = await em.find(Post, {});
    const repo = em.getRepository(Post)
    const multiplePosts = await repo.find({ _id: { $in: [new ObjectId("6005d0c253e2b72af07fc61a")] }  });
    console.log("multiplePosts: ", multiplePosts);
    return posts;
}
```

> Post.ts

```
export class Post {

  @Field(() => ID)
  @PrimaryKey()
  _id!: string;

  @Field(() => String)
  @Property()
  createdAt = new Date();

  @Field(() => String)
  @Property({ onUpdate: () => new Date() })
  updatedAt = new Date();

  @Field(() => String)
  @Property()
  title!: string;

  @Field(() => String)
  @Property()
  excerpt!: string;

  @Field(() => String)
  @Property()
  content!: string;

  @Field()
  @ManyToOne()
  author!: User;
}
```

Here's the error I am getting:

```
src/resolvers/PostResolver.ts:32:43 - error TS2769: No overload matches this call.
  Overload 1 of 2, '(where: FilterQuery<Post>, options?: FindOptions<Post, any> | undefined): Promise<Post[]>', gave the following error.      
    Argument of type '{ _id: { $in: ObjectId[]; }; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'FilterQuery<Post>'.
      Types of property '_id' are incompatible.
        Type '{ $in: ObjectId[]; }' is not assignable to type 'string | RegExp | OperatorMap<FilterValue2<string>> | FilterValue2<string>[] |n 
ull | undefined'.
          Types of property '$in' are incompatible.
            Type 'ObjectId[]' is not assignable to type 'FilterValue2<string>[]'.
              Type 'ObjectId' is not assignable to type 'FilterValue2<string>'.
                Type 'ObjectId' is missing the following properties from type 'RegExp': exec, test, source, global, and 13 more.
  Overload 2 of 2, '(where: FilterQuery<Post>, populate?: any, orderBy?: QueryOrderMap | undefined, limit?: number | undefined, offset?: number | undefined): Promise<...>', gave the following error.
    Argument of type '{ _id: { $in: ObjectId[]; }; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'FilterQuery<Post>'.
      Types of property '_id' are incompatible.
        Type '{ $in: ObjectId[]; }' is not assignable to type 'string | RegExp | OperatorMap<FilterValue2<string>> | FilterValue2<string>[] | null | undefined'.
          Types of property '$in' are incompatible.
            Type 'ObjectId[]' is not assignable to type 'FilterValue2<string>[]'.

32     const multiplePosts = await repo.find({
                                             ~
33       _id: { $in: [new ObjectId("6005d0c253e2b72af07fc61a")] },
   ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
34     });
   ~~~~~


    at createTSError (D:\blog\server\node_modules\ts-node\src\index.ts:513:12)
    at reportTSError (D:\blog\server\node_modules\ts-node\src\index.ts:517:19)
    at getOutput (D:\blog\server\node_modules\ts-node\src\index.ts:752:36)
    at Object.compile (D:\blog\server\node_modules\ts-node\src\index.ts:968:32)
    at Module.m._compile (D:\blog\server\node_modules\ts-node\src\index.ts:1056:42)
    at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1137:10)
    at Object.require.extensions.<computed> [as .ts] (D:\blog\server\node_modules\ts-node\src\index.ts:1059:12)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:973:32)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:813:14)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:997:19)
```

Removing the ObjectId makes the typescript compiler happy, but then MongoDB is not treating them as Object ID.

Edited: Also, adding `//ts-ignore` works fine, so it's a type issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue comes from your entity definition, where you are explicitly saying that the `_id` type is `string`, not `ObjectId`. So if it is an object id, fix the definition:

```
  @PrimaryKey()
  _id!: ObjectId;
```

Then your query should pass. Note that you can also define serialized PK `id: string` that will act as a virtual getter for the string version of the ObjectId.

https://mikro-orm.io/docs/usage-with-mongo/

> You might need to install `@types/mongodb`.

In general if the property type is ObjectId, it is possible to query by string form too. Those should be equal:

```
repo.find({ _id: { $in: [new ObjectId("6005d0c253e2b72af07fc61a")] } });
repo.find({ _id: { $in: ["6005d0c253e2b72af07fc61a"] } });
repo.find({ _id: [new ObjectId("6005d0c253e2b72af07fc61a")] });
repo.find({ _id: ["6005d0c253e2b72af07fc61a"] });
repo.find([new ObjectId("6005d0c253e2b72af07fc61a")]);
repo.find(["6005d0c253e2b72af07fc61a"]);
```

Also note that unless you are using ts-morph, you should be putting explicit types where you use property initializer:

```
  @Property()
  createdAt: Date = new Date();
```

https://mikro-orm.io/docs/metadata-providers/#limitations-and-requirements

Comment: Thank you for your reply. That was the mistake I was doing. I have checked this [link](https://mikro-orm.io/docs/usage-with-mongo/#objectid-and-string-id-duality) and edited the entity accordingly: `@PrimaryKey()
  _id!: ObjectId;

  @Field(() => ID)
  @SerializedPrimaryKey()
  id!: string`

But now, ` const multiplePosts = await repo.find({
      id: { $in: [new ObjectId("6005d0c253e2b72af07fc61a")] },
    });` is giving me error.

Comment: Yes, that should be quite obvious. Why would you feed objectid to string property?

Comment: I found it in docs: https://mikro-orm.io/docs/usage-with-mongo/#objectid-and-string-id-duality

On it, _id and id are the same

Comment: Well they are not the same, one is typed as string, the other as objectid. And this is exactly the same problem as your original one. It might be possible programatically, we are talking about TS issues, not runtime errors.

Comment: I get it, I was a bit confused with type errors and runtime errors. Thanks for clearing me out. That's why `repo.find({ _id: ["6005d0c253e2b72af07fc61a"] });` is also not working as `string[] != ObjectId[]`

Comment: Is there a way to make typescript okay with `repo.find({ _id: ["6005d0c253e2b72af07fc61a"] });`?

Comment: You can always use `expr` helper to to get around typings issues: `repo.find({ [expr('_id')]: ["6005d0c253e2b72af07fc61a"] });`.